# Limiting the perfomance of a graphics card to prevent an error

Tags: nvidia, graphics, troubleshooting

I have a pc with some problem either with the graphic card or with it's interface.

When i use the pc at max resolution it doesn't work or get stuck. But when i reduce the resolution somewhat it works. So i use it with reduced resolution ,it's OK - except for the following problem :

It works well for everything web related - surfing, video, etc - but it get stuck after playing candy crush for some period of time(and maybe other games, haven't tested).

My guess is that the game somehow overloads the graphics card. So are there any way to limit performance other than resolution , preferably ways that might make sense for the game ?

The card is from nvidia , probably 200 series.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you have? Do you have the proprietary drivers for the graphics card installed?

Comment: I think 14.04, I'm not sure i have proprietary drivers. But i;m sure it won't solve the bug because the computer is also problematic under windows. But does the driver had the limiting function ?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with performance. Open the Additional Drivers app to install it.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like the graphics card is getting too hot when it is working hard and the driver is shutting it down to protect it. Are you monitoring the temperature of your graphics card using lm-sensor and p-sensor?

It would be worth checking that the graphics card heatsink and fan are not clogged with dust and that the graphics card fan has not failed.

To reduce the load on the graphics card from a game you can
1 reduce the resolution
2 limit the FPS (frames per second)
3 reduce the detail
4 turn off effects like shadows
5 turn off antialiasing

Most games have options for doing this.